# Alternating sum of binomial coefficients $\sum(-1)^k{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q:Calculate the sum:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}\frac{1}{k+1} $$

Comment: You probably only meant one $(-1)^k$. Also, did you want to sum from $1$ or $0$?

Comment: The identity $$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$ could prove helpful

Comment: This sum can also be done by using $(k+1)^{-1}= \int_{0}^{1} x^k ~dx$. So the sum=$\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^n=1/(n+1).$

Answer (score 7):

Let

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}\qquad; f(0)=0$$
so 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k}x^{k}=(1-x)^n-1$$
hence
$$f(x)=\frac{-1}{n+1}(1-x)^{n+1}-x+\frac{1}{n+1}$$

What's $f(1)=-\frac{n}{n+1}$?

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac1{k+1}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n+1}{k+1}\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k}\\
&=\frac1{n+1}\left(1-(n+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n+1}{k}\right)\\
&=-\frac n{n+1}
\end{align}
$$