# Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Calculate  $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}$, I do not know hot get rid of that $k$, for me it is similar like  $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{k}{n} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, do you have some idea?

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604173/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-sum-1kn-choose-k-frac1k1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. There is no closed formula here. Compute the first few terms and compare them with the $n$th-[harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$. What can we conjecture?

P.S. BTW the linked sum $\sum(-1)^k{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k+1}$ is "similar" but quite much easier (it has a closed formula).

Comment: it is the same but how to prove that

Comment: You can try by induction or by an "integral" trick by considering $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k{n\choose k}x^{k-1}$.

Comment: Actually, there is a closed formula: see answer below

Comment: @GCab Maybe we do not agree with the same definition of "closed formula". However it is true that Stirling numbers of the first kind can be written by using harmonic numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_by_harmonic_numbers

Answer (score 2):

We can write your sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){1 \over k}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right){1 \over {k + 1}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k + 1 \cr}  \right){1 \over {k + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {t_k }  \cr} 
$$

and we can express it in terms of a [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), since
$$
\eqalign{
  & t_0  = \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right) = n  \cr 
  & {{t_{k + 1} } \over {t_k }} =  - {{n^{\,\underline {\,k + 2\,} } } \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)!}}
 {{\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {k + 1} \right)!} \over {n^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }} =   \cr 
  &  =  - {{\left( {n - 1 - k} \right)} \over 1}{{\left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)}}
 = {{\left( {k - n + 1} \right)\left( {k + 1} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 2} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)}} \cr} 
$$

Then
$$
f(n) = n\;{}_3F_2 \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   { - n + 1,\;1,\;1}  \cr 
   {2,\;2}  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;1} \right)
$$

Alternatively, we have that
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(n + 1) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n + 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){1 \over k}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){1 \over k}}  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right){1 \over k}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){1 \over k}}  + {1 \over {n + 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n + 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n + 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right){1 \over k}}  - {1 \over {n + 1}}\left( {0^{\,n + 1}  - 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = f(n) + {1 \over {n + 1}} \cr} 
$$
i.e.:
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  f(0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  f(1) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  f(n + 1) - f(n) = \Delta f(n) = {1 \over {n + 1}} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

or
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  g(n) = n!f(n) \hfill \cr 
  g(0) = 0 \hfill \cr 
  g(1) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  g(n + 1) = \left( {n + 1} \right)f(n) + n! \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and this is the recurrence satified by 
$$g(n)=\left[ \matrix{  n+1  \cr   2 \cr}  \right]$$
where $\left[ \matrix{  n  \cr   m \cr}  \right]$ represents the (unsigned) Stirling number of 1st kind.

Thus
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
f(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k + 1} \binom{n}{k}{1 \over k}}
  = {1 \over {n!}}\left[ \matrix{  n + 1 \cr   2 \cr}  \right]
}$$

Also refer to [OEIS seq. A000254](http://oeis.org/A000254) .

Answer (score 1):

This problem and its type appear  at MSE regularly. Suppose we seek to
compute

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}.$$

With this in mind we introduce the function

$$f(z) = n! (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{z^2} \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}.$$

We then obtain for $1\le k\le n$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z) =
(-1)^{n+1} \frac{n!}{k^2} \prod_{q=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k-q}
\prod_{q=k+1}^n \frac{1}{k-q}
\\ = (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n!}{k}
\frac{1}{k!} \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}
= {n\choose k} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}.$$

This means that

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathrm{Res}_{z=k} f(z)$$

and since residues sum to zero we have

$$S_n + \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) + \mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) = 0.$$

We can compute  the residue at infinity by inspection  (it is zero) or
more formally through

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty}
n! (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{z^2} \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}
\\ = - n! (-1)^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^2 \prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{1/z-q}
\\ = - n! (-1)^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{z}{1-qz}
\\ = - n! (-1)^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} z^n
\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{1-qz} = 0.$$

We get for the residue at $z=0$ that

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z) =
n! (-1)^{n+1}
\left. \left(\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}\right)'\right|_{z=0}
\\ = - n! (-1)^{n+1} \left.
\left(\prod_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q}\right)
\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{z-q} \right|_{z=0}
\\ = n! (-1)^n \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} \left(-H_{n}\right)
= -H_n.$$

We thus have $S_n - H_n = 0$ or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S_n = H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.}$$